# php inserir com formato datetime

Tags: php

É o seguinte eu tenho 2 variáveis:

Variável data formato (aaaa/mm/dd):

```
$inserir_data = nl2br( addslashes($_POST['inserir_data']));
```

E um turno do tipo VARCHAR que contem 2 horas esta no formato (hh:mm-hh:mm):

```
$inserir_turno = nl2br( addslashes($_POST['inserir_turno']));
```

Utilizei isto para separar o turno em 2 variáveis e depois juntei a data normal com o turno para formar um date time e inserir na base de dados numa variavl do tipo date time:

```
$turno_separado = explode('-', $inserir_turno);

$hora_inicio = "$alterar_data $turno_separado[0]";
$hora_final  = "$alterar_data $turno_separado[1]";
```

O problema é que pelo que vejo está tudo correto mas ele não insere na base de dados na base de dados fica sempre (00-00-00 00:00:00)

Ajudem-me que eu não faço a mínima ideia do que se passa aqui será da forma como estou a inserir? devido ao facto de na base de dados estar datetime e ele nao reconhecer a variável?

Obrigado pela paciência!! Espero que me possam ajudar!

Comment: Talvez seria melhor trabalhar sempre com DATETIME no mysql ao invés de VARCHAR, e com a classe DateTime no PHP para extrair com o formato desejado. Fora que os turnos ficariam melhores em colunas diferentes, assim provavelmente parte da logica seria resolvido na query.

Comment: Mas foi vc quem desenvolveu a base de dados? Acho que esta a ir pelo caminho das pedras, sendo que mysql e php tem funcionalidades para data e hora que resolvem muita coisa sem precisar ficar se matando assim,  fora os problemas que vc vai evitar com erros de calculos. Mas faça como desejar, apenas estou dando uma sugestão ;)

Comment: Shider, não leve a mal, mas é mais fácil do jeito que fez porque já esta feito e porque é a unica forma que vc conhece, se conhecer a fundo o funcionamento de funções que trabalham com tempo real e não com CHAR ou STRING, vai perceber que na verdade você esta apenas tentando recriar a roda sem necessidade. Não é porque vc só conhece um caminho que isso o torna o melhor, trabalhar com das assim pode ser um grande problema. Desejo sorte com isso ai e se quiser depois dar uma olhada nas classes de "Date" do PHP e ver os exemplos talvez no futuro vc consiga refatorar seus códigos. Feliz 2018

Comment: php: http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php - mysql: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html - Unix Time: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time e por ultimo perguntas sobra comparar tempo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=comparar+datas+%5Bphp%5D e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=comparar%20datas%20%5bmysql%5d

Comment: Não é do input, o tipo DATE só vai existir no mysql, a classe de nome DateTime do PHP vc vai usar pra comparar strings (o seu input) com o formato que veio do mysql dos campos tipo DATE.

Comment: Eu queria fornecer um exemplo, mas não sei bem o que fez até agora fica meio dificil imaginar por onde começar, pois inicialmente o seu problema é outro, mesmo que causado por trabalhar strings como se fossem datas. Não tem solução mágica, algumas coisas vai ter que refazer ou simplesmente arriscar no que já fez até agora e no futuro quando entender melhor o conceito de TEMPO refatorar/refazer seus códigos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Tabela de exemplo

Primeiro vamos tomar como base a seguinte tabela criada no mysql:

```
+-------------------------+
|datetime_inicio datetime |
+-------------------------+
|datetime_fim    datetime | 
+-------------------------+
```

## Consertando o codigo atual

E agora fazer seu codigo funcionar (antes de sugerir qualquer melhoria!). O seu codigo apresentou apenas um pequeno erro na hora de executar. Aparentemente a variavel `$alterar_hora` estava indefinido (imagino que você queria usar `$inserir_data`). Fazendo essa alterar, o codigo ficou assim:

```
<?php

//formato ano/mes/dia ou YYYY/mm/dd
$_POST['inserir_data'] = '2018/1/1';
$inserir_data = nl2br( addslashes($_POST['inserir_data']));

//formato ano/mes/dia ou YYYY/mm/dd
$_POST['inserir_turno'] = '10:30-11:40';
$inserir_turno = nl2br( addslashes($_POST['inserir_turno']));

$turno_separado = explode('-', $inserir_turno);

$hora_inicio = "$inserir_data $turno_separado[0]";
$hora_final  = "$inserir_data $turno_separado[1]";

var_dump($hora_inicio);
var_dump($hora_final);

$conexao = mysqli_connect('host', 'usuario', 'senha', 'nome_banco');
mysqli_query($conexao, 'insert into teste (datatime_inicio, datetime_fim) values (\'' 
. $hora_inicio . '\',\'' . $hora_final .'\')');

//exibir erros na execução da instrução anterior (remover em produção).
echo mysqli_error($conexao);
```

O que tem de diferente em relação ao seu codigo são os escapes "\'" para permitir uma aspa simples fique dentro de outra aspa simples, ja que strings precisam estar entre aspas. Após algumas execuções do codigo acima, a tabela no banco ficará similar a:

```
+----------------------+--------------------+
|datetime_inicio       |datetime_fim        |
+----------------------+--------------------+
|2018-01-01 10:30:00   |2018-01-01 11:40:00 |
|2018-01-01 10:30:00   |2018-01-01 11:40:00 |
|2018-01-01 10:30:00   |2018-01-01 11:40:00 |
+----------------------+--------------------+
```

## Melhorias

É claro que você poderia usar algo similar a essa tag `<input type="datetime-local" name="bdaytime">` para pegar o datetime completo, e so validar no servidor.Embora isso não funciona em todos os navegadores (mas da para usar plugins que permitem isso).

Comment: Muito obrigado você salvou-me a vida muito obrigado pela paciência e desculpe o tempo perdido!! Obrigado mesmo Feliz Ano Novo!